# Why I am getting null

Tags: java, null

Can some please help me to solve this problem. when I try to print getCorrectAnswer  it is printing null. how can I getCorrectAnswer to print the correctAnswer  thanks.

```
public class Test1 {

    private String correctAnswer;

    public String getCorrectAnswer() {
        return correctAnswer;
    }

    public void setUpCorrectAnswer() {
        if (1 == 1) {
            correctAnswer = "a";
        } else {
            correctAnswer = "d";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 a = new Test1();
        System.out.println(" Answer " + a.getCorrectAnswer());
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think it should print and why?

Comment: setUpCorrectAnswer is never called, that's because.

Comment: I would write the answer if this wasn't so trivial... where is `setUpCorrectAnswer()` called?? Please, read your code!!

Comment: Smells like homework to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use your `setUpCorrectAnswer()` method to set the value.

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
  Test1 a = new Test1();
  a.setUpCorrectAnswer(); // here
  System.out.println(" Answer " + a.getCorrectAnswer());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call setUpCorrectAnswer().

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test1 a = new Test1();
    a.setUpCorrectAnswer();
    System.out.println(" Answer " + a.getCorrectAnswer());
}
```